# Enter to remote system with click

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, bash, ssh

I got a new MacBook pro and before I've win that I use the mobaextream software to connect to remote sys, when I configure ssh in moba I once enter private key (I browse the file ) and then every time that I want to access to that machine I just open moba and double click on the required system and Im In.
in mac I didn't find a way to do it I open the bash and when I connect with ssh I need to add the user password , any Idea how can I configure it **once** ?

http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

any idea if there is software which I can use that help me to manage all this remote system ?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy in the private key from your Windows system and place it in the .ssh subfolder of your user's home folder on the Mac.

You can then use the private key when logging from the command line - having to enter the passphrase for the key every time (if you have a passphrase on it).

If you want to enter the password only once per boot, then run "ssh-add" to add it to your local agent.

If you want a more GUI oriented application you can use a program such as "SSH Shell" that you'll find in the Mac App Store.